# Pattern Copying of a file Using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file which has content as follows

```
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqr
stuvwx
```

I want to place this content into another file which should look like

```
ab
cd
ef
gh
ij
kl
mn
op
qr
st
uv
wx
```

How do I do it using python ??

Comment: Have You tried something? if yes then Show us
Its just some basic string manipulation

Answer (score 2):

Well, after updating your question, my code is now irrelevant to your solution, but I have combined what I have below into this:

```
''' Split by n number of delimeters
'''
def splitByNDelims(s, n, d):
    return d.join(s[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(s),n))

outputFile = open('outputFile.txt', 'w')

with open('inputFile.txt', 'r') as inputFile:
    for line in inputFile:
        outputFile.write(splitByNDelims(line, 2, '\n') + '\n')

outputFile.close()
```

Example: [@Python Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/python-string-split-new-line)

*I will keep my original answer below for others.*

---

### String manipulation using list comprehension

#### Break the problem down into 2 parts

```
myStr = "abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuvwx"

def superJoin(aStr, n):
    return ' '.join([subJoin(part, n) for part in aStr.split(' ')])

def subJoin(aStr, n):
    return ' '.join([aStr[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(aStr), n)])

print superJoin(myStr, 2)
print superJoin(myStr, 3)
```

***Output:***

```
ab cd ef gh ij kl mn op qr st uv wx
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx
```

#### Combine into 1 function

```
def comboJoin(s, n, d):
    return d.join([d.join([p[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(p),n)]) for p in s.split(' ')])

print comboJoin(myStr, 2, '-')
```

***Output:***

```
ab-cd-ef-gh-ij-kl-mn-op-qr-st-uv-wx
```

#### Preproccess the string to remove white-space

If you preprocess the string and remove the whitespace, you can join by any number divisible by the length of the string:

```
def simpleJoin(s, n, d):
    t = s.replace(' ', '') 
    return d.join(t[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(t), n))

print simpleJoin(myStr, 2, '-')
print simpleJoin(myStr, 3, '-')
print simpleJoin(myStr, 4, '-')
print simpleJoin(myStr, 6, '-')
print simpleJoin(myStr, 8, '-')
print simpleJoin(myStr, 12, '-')
```

***Output:***

```
ab-cd-ef-gh-ij-kl-mn-op-qr-st-uv-wx
abc-def-ghi-jkl-mno-pqr-stu-vwx
abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop-qrst-uvwx
abcdef-ghijkl-mnopqr-stuvwx
abcdefgh-ijklmnop-qrstuvwx
abcdefghijkl-mnopqrstuvwx
```